# google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Required field name cannot be null

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, pydantic

I am attempting to ingest a CSV file into BigQuery, however, it is complaining about the field being null. The field `name` which was null has been replaced with 0, however, I still get the following error.

Here's what the field looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name':['NaN','NaN','NaN'})

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class sample(BaseModel):

    id: str = Field()

    name: str = Field(
      description="name",
      categorical=True
    )


raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Required field name cannot be null




SELECT
    GENERATE_UUID()                       as id
    , SAFE_CAST(t1.name AS STRING)        as name
  from
    table1 t1
;
```

Comment: How was the table created?  Is the `name` field required, which is how bigquery describes `not null`? Can you post the code which causes the error?

Comment: Is there a way to make the field non-required? Using `pydantic` to create the schema.

Comment: @StevenEnsslen ^

Comment: I haven't used `pydantic`in that way. I believe that the field just needs to be `typing.Optional` in the dataclass.  You'll need to drop the table by hand to make the change.